# How can I loop encode/decoding data from socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, portaudio, opus

I'm currently working on a voice transmission software in C++ using PortAudio and Opus for the sound related part and Boost Asio for the network part.

I encounter difficulties while trying to setup encoding and decoding in a loop.

To be more precise I have a function who handle the "calling" part of my project, this function is launch when 2 people accept to call with each other.

I got 2 different functions, one when the client accept the call, and the second when the client initiate the call.

Both functions are build in the same way, I start initialize every libraries that I need, then I listen to the socket for audio data to decode and send encoded audio data to the socket.

My issue is : I'm trying to do this in a while statement with the simple condition : if(clientConnected) {} but it seems that the code is doing only one loop turn and then block and I don't know why.

(I know that cause the std::cout << dataSize is only printed once)

This is one of the 2 call functions (receiveCall) (if you have any question ask me) :

```cpp
void Window::receiveCall(const std::string& ip) {

    // Initialize PortAudio and Opus
    PortAudioWrapper portAudio;
    OpusWrapper opus;
    if (!portAudio.OpenDefaultStream(1, 1, paFloat32, 48000, 960))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open PortAudio stream" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if (!opus.Init(48000, 2, OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP))
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize Opus" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    if (!portAudio.StartStream())
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to start PortAudio stream" << std::endl;
        return;
    }
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(ioService);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioService);

    try
    {
        // Create an acceptor to listen for incoming connections
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ip), 12345);
        acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
        acceptor.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
        acceptor.bind(endpoint);
        acceptor.listen();

        std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connection on " << ip << ":12345" << std::endl;

        // Wait for a client to connect

        acceptor.accept(socket);

        std::cout << "Connected to client at " << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl;
        bool clientConnected = true;

        // Create a buffer to hold the audio data
        std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(1276);

        // Send and receive audio data
        while (clientConnected)
        {
            // Read audio data from PortAudio
            float audioData[960 * 2 * sizeof(float)];
            portAudio.readStream(audioData, 960);
            
            // Compress the audio data using Opus
            int dataSize = opus.Encode(audioData, 960, buffer.data(), 1276);
            std::cout << "dataSize : "<< dataSize << std::endl;
            // Send the compressed audio data to the client
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(buffer.data(), dataSize));

            // Receive compressed audio data from the client
            boost::system::error_code error;
            dataSize = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), error);
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            {
                std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl;
                clientConnected = false; // set flag to false when client disconnects
            }
            else if (error)
            {
                std::cerr << "Error receiving audio data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                clientConnected = false; // set flag to false when client disconnects
            }

            // Decompress the audio data using Opus
            float decodedData[960 * 2 * sizeof(float)];
            int numSamples = opus.Decode(buffer.data(), dataSize, decodedData, 960);

            // Write the decompressed audio data to PortAudio
            portAudio.writeStream(decodedData, numSamples);
        }
    }    
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception in receiveCall: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    // Cleanup code
    socket.close();
    acceptor.close();
    portAudio.StopStream();
}
```

The problem is probably in the loop but I don't know what it could be.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is probably others possibility that could set this code wrong, I have one in mind : 
blocking function ?

Comment: Oh, that's pretty much the only thing that can be expected here: random guesses and possibilities. Since the shown code is not a [mre], noone can cut/paste, then compile, run, and debug the shown code themselves. So, proposing various possibilities is, pretty much, as much as can be done here. Additionally, you're making unwarranted assumptions as to who did or did not downvote which questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Opus side and buffer dimensioning (with caveats) uses 2-channel. Yet you initialize the PA stream with only one channel. That's probably a mistake.

Besides, there is a lack of framing. Your code simple assumes that whatever is "sent" in one call is also received in one call to `read_some`. As the name implies, this is just not the case. It reads "some".

Since you seem to know that `1276` is the upperbound for the encoded data size, you could avoid framing by hardcoding the chosen buffer lengths, channel count and sample formats for your peers. Then you could instead use a asio::read to composed-read one or more `read_some` operations to read 'the entire buffer' (or to EOF):

```
dataSize = read(socket, asio::buffer(buffer), error);
```

Of course this requires the sending to ignore the `dataSize` to work:

```
write(socket, asio::buffer(buffer /*, dataSize*/));
```

However, the `Decode` call needs to know `dataSize`, so you still have to transmit it.

### Other Issues

I think the dimensions of the `audioData` and `decodedAudio` buffers are off. Fortunately on the "too large" side. I think the `* sizeof(float)` factor is wrong. I'd use C++ arrays anyways:

```
struct sample { float chan0, chan1; };
std::array<sample, 960> audioData, decodedData;
```

Now you can avoid hardcoding the `960` magic number in various places too!

### Sending big-endian datasize

Using Boost Endian to represent 32-bit integers portably on the wire:

```
using NetSize = boost::endian::big_uint32_t;
```

Now sending could look like:

```
NetSize dataSize = opus.Encode(audioData.data(), audioData.size(), buffer.data(), buffer.size());
std::cout << "dataSize : " << dataSize << std::endl;

// Send the compressed audio data to the client
write(socket,
      std::array{
          asio::buffer(&dataSize, sizeof(dataSize)),
          asio::buffer(buffer, dataSize),
      });
```

And receiving similarly, but in two steps:

```
read(socket, asio::buffer(&dataSize, sizeof(dataSize)), error);
if (error) {
    dataSize = 0;
} else {
    dataSize = read(socket, asio::buffer(buffer, dataSize), error);
}
```

### Putting It All Together

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07bac17e9ff51944)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/endian/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;

using NetSize = boost::endian::big_uint32_t;

enum { paFloat32 };
struct PortAudioWrapper {
    unsigned channels_ = 0;
    float    val_      = 0;

    bool OpenDefaultStream(int, int channels, int format, unsigned, int) {
        channels_ = channels;
        assert(format == paFloat32);
        return true;
    }

    bool StartStream() { return true; }
    bool StopStream() { return true; }

    // float audioData[960 * 2 * sizeof(float)];
    bool writeStream(void const* buf, size_t n) {
        float const* fp = static_cast<float const*>(buf);
        assert(n);
        auto val = *fp;
        std::cerr << "writing " << channels_ << "x" << n << " of " << val //
                  << " (all equal: " << std::boolalpha
                  << std::all_of(fp, fp + channels_ * n, [val](float sample) { return sample == val; })
                  << " )" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    bool readStream(void* buf, size_t n) {
        float* fp = static_cast<float *>(buf);
        val_ += 1.111;
        std::cerr << "recording " << channels_ << "x" << n << " of audio " << val_ << std::endl;
        std::fill_n(fp, channels_ * n, val_);
        return true;
    }
};

enum { OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP };
struct OpusWrapper {
    unsigned channels_ = 0;

    bool Init(unsigned, unsigned channels, int) {
        channels_ = channels;
        return true;
    };

    int Encode(void const* pcm, size_t numsamples, uint8_t* buf, size_t bufsize) {
        assert(numsamples);

        numsamples = 1; // we just encode 1 sample - it's awesome compression!
        size_t const n = numsamples * channels_ * sizeof(float);
        assert(n <= bufsize);
        std::copy_n(static_cast<uint8_t const*>(pcm), n, buf);
        return n;
    }

    int Decode(uint8_t const* buf, size_t bufsize, void* pcm, size_t sampleroom) {
        int const samplesize = channels_ * sizeof(float);
        assert(samplesize);
        size_t const n = bufsize / samplesize;
        assert(n <= sampleroom);

        assert(bufsize >= n);
        std::copy_n(buf, n, static_cast<uint8_t*>(pcm));
        return n;
    }
};

struct Window {
    void receiveCall(std::string const& ip) {
        // Initialize PortAudio and Opus
        PortAudioWrapper portAudio;
        OpusWrapper      opus;
        if (!portAudio.OpenDefaultStream(1, 2, paFloat32, 48000, 960)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to open PortAudio stream" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        if (!opus.Init(48000, 2, OPUS_APPLICATION_VOIP)) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to initialize Opus" << std::endl;
            return;
        }
        if (!portAudio.StartStream()) {
            std::cerr << "Failed to start PortAudio stream" << std::endl;
            return;
        }

        assert(portAudio.channels_ == opus.channels_);
        asio::io_service ioService;
        tcp::socket      socket(ioService);
        tcp::acceptor    acceptor(ioService);

        try {
            // Create an acceptor to listen for incoming connections
            tcp::endpoint endpoint{asio::ip::address::from_string(ip), 12345};
            acceptor.open(endpoint.protocol());
            acceptor.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
            acceptor.bind(endpoint);
            acceptor.listen();

            std::cout << "Waiting for incoming connection on " << ip << ":12345" << std::endl;

            // Wait for a client to connect

            acceptor.accept(socket);

            std::cout << "Connected to client at " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            bool clientConnected = true;

            // Create a buffer to hold the audio data
            std::array<unsigned char, 1276> buffer;

            // Send and receive audio data
            while (clientConnected) {
                // Read audio data from PortAudio
                struct sample { float chan0, chan1; };
                std::array<sample, 960> audioData, decodedData;
                static_assert(sizeof(audioData) == 2 * 960 * sizeof(float));
                static_assert(sizeof(decodedData) == 2 * 960 * sizeof(float));

                portAudio.readStream(audioData.data(), audioData.size());

                // Compress the audio data using Opus
                NetSize dataSize = opus.Encode(audioData.data(), audioData.size(), buffer.data(), buffer.size());
                std::cout << "dataSize : " << dataSize << std::endl;

                // Send the compressed audio data to the client
                write(socket,
                      std::array{
                          asio::buffer(&dataSize, sizeof(dataSize)),
                          asio::buffer(buffer, dataSize),
                      });

                // Receive compressed audio data from the client
                boost::system::error_code error;
                read(socket, asio::buffer(&dataSize, sizeof(dataSize)), error);
                if (error) {
                    dataSize = 0;
                } else {
                    dataSize = read(socket, asio::buffer(buffer, dataSize), error);
                }

                clientConnected = !error.failed(); // set flag to false when client disconnects
                if (error == asio::error::eof) {
                    std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl;
                } else if (error) {
                    std::cerr << "Error receiving audio data: " << error.message() << std::endl;
                }

                // Decompress the audio data using Opus
                assert(dataSize <= buffer.size());
                int numSamples = opus.Decode(buffer.data(), dataSize, decodedData.data(), decodedData.size());

                // Write the decompressed audio data to PortAudio
                portAudio.writeStream(decodedData.data(), numSamples);
            }
        } catch (std::exception& e) {
            std::cerr << "Exception in receiveCall: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        // Cleanup code
        socket.close();
        acceptor.close();
        portAudio.StopStream();
    }
};

int main() {
    Window w;
    w.receiveCall("127.0.0.1");
}
```

Coliru output:

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp 
./a.out&
sleep 1; nc 127.0.0.1 12345 -w 1 | od -A none -f
Waiting for incoming connection on 127.0.0.1:12345
Connected to client at 127.0.0.1:34176
recording 2x960 of audio 1.111
dataSize : 8
Client disconnected
a.out: main.cpp:26: bool PortAudioWrapper::writeStream(const void*, size_t): Assertion `n' failed.
     3.85186e-34           1.111           1.111
bash: line 9:  7295 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
```

Of course, the "peer" doesn't send back a valid frame with opus data.

[image]

Comment: Here's a version refactored to show an actual "voice call" http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb0fea9a37ca76f7. Note there is still a problem with the fact that it is all synchronous and  you're doing "faux full duplex" ("_dull fuplex_"?) in a turn-by-turn manner. It means that both sides are step-locked even if one lags.

Comment: A true full-duplex async session implementation would look like this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b081aeaeb76532